# How can I get Google Chrome multitouch support like in OS X?

Tags: touchpad, multi-touch, macosx

In OS X Google Chrome, swiping left or right with two fingers goes forward or back in the history. I've been trying to use synaptics and touchegg to do this but can't seem to figure it out. How can I emulate this behavior in Ubuntu? I have a Macbook Air.

Comment: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/03/ubuntus-utouch-tech-brings-smooth-scrolling-to-chromium/ Here's an awesome video on progress being made.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest trying [easystroke](http://packages.ubuntu.com/easystroke) for this task. I have not used it myself (since my touchpad does not support multitouch :(...).

```
sudo apt-get install easystroke
```

BTW, Chrome does not have the feature in Ubuntu because while Ubuntu does support multitouch through the use of a tech called utouch, most applications and toolkits do not yet support utouch, and are waiting on X to pick up multitouch support itself, which is probably the better solution.

Comment: Thanks. I saw that the multitouch stuff was finally accepted into the kernel. Hopefully Ubuntu will pick this up soon. Probably not before 12.04?